# How to generate a keypair of a existing SSH key using azure ARM or sdk Java code

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, ssh-keys

I have created an SSHKey on the azure cloud using below ARM template (Ref: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/sshpublickeys))

```
{
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "sshkeyname",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys",
    "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
    "properties": {}
}
```

After successful deployment I can see that ssh key is created on azure cloud, but don't have public key. Now I want to generate the public key for this key. I know using `ssh-keygen` command I can generate it, but I want to know is there any possibility to generate using ARM template. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to generate the SSH public key if you do not provide it. When you create the SSH key pair in the Azure portal, then you can see the ssh key pair like this:

[image]

Azure generates the public key for you to set as the value of `publicKey`. But inARM template, you need to provide it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Actually at first generated keys then I used those for an existing SSH key available at Azure, hence I solved my problem.

Comment: @Achintya Yes, the SSH key is the first thing you need to create yourself. Do you mind accept it as the answer if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available **only** through the REST api (i.e. as a data plane operation), not through ARM.

Something like:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys/{sshPublicKeyName}/generateKeyPair?api-version=2022-11-01
```

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/ssh-public-keys/generate-key-pair?tabs=HTTP